# Get DataMembers from DLL assembly using System.Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, system.reflection

I'm trying to use `Assembly` class to get `[DataMember]'s` from my `[ServiceContract]`. The problem is, my method returns an empty collection...

Here's my code:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);
Type c = assembly.GetType(fullName);
var dataMembers = c.GetFields().Where(f => f.GetCustomAttributes<DataContractFormatAttribute>().Any());
```

And here's my service class:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class MyService
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Test;

    [DataMember]
    public Int64 ComeAndGetMe;

    public bool AmIUseless;

    [OperationContract]
    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

I want to get `Test` and `ComeAndGetMe`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No fields are marked `[DataContractFormat]`, so looking for `<DataContractFormatAttribute>` will not find anything. Try looking for fields where `DataMemberAttribute` is specified.

Minor point, but personally I think you should make those *properties*, not *fields* (and use `GetProperties()`, obviously):

```
[DataMember]
public string Test {get;set;}
[DataMember]
public long ComeAndGetMe {get;set;}
// etc
```

Comment: But there's no such a thing like `DataMemberAttribute`. VS2012 shows it red

Comment: @Nickon then you are probably missing an assembly reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.dll, or a using directive to `System.Runtime.Serialization` - however, since `[DataMember]` ***is*** `DataMemberAttribute`, I think we can say it exists!

Comment: Still nothing like `DataMemberAttribute` :/

Comment: @Nickon [DataMemberAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx). MSDN even tells you what assembly you need to reference

Comment: It was a reference, but it's working now. I had to restart VS:))) Many thanks!